# Polling for notification for destination: has exceeded polling attempts for transaction

Tags: 2013-sp1, deployer

I am trying to publish a dynamic component which has around 150 multimedia component links and around 20 dynamic component links. In short, the single publish transaction is supposed to publish 170 components. I am getting below error during the Commit Deployment phase:

> Polling for notification for destination: K72TVTs2ioqWehu39TbcHA== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-122471-66560.

As suggested in few other posts, I have verified that enough space is available on deployer. 
Is there any threshold value for #of components that gets published in a single publishing transaction?

Comment: do you get any errors or warnings in the logs of your deployment webservice ?

Comment: Can you mark an answer as complete?

Answer (score 4):

This may probably be because size of the package.
Ensure in your `httpupload`module (assuming you have a .NET content Delivery setup) you have following section added in the `web.config` file

```
  <system.web>
    <!-- 50MB in kilobytes, default is 4096 or 4MB-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024000" />   </system.web>   <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 or approx. 28.6102 Mb-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000" /> 
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>   </system.webServer>
```

Ensure the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` are large enough to accommodate your publish package. By default there is a limit of 4MB on the package size by IIS.

If you have a Java based content delivery, you may need to do an equivalent configuration for the same.

Comment: We are using java based content delivery and we have verified that relevant counterpart setting already exists in cd_deployer_conf.xml. <HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="2097152000" Location="/applications/tridion/deployer_webapp/incoming"
        InProcessDeploy="true" />

Answer (score 4):

That error doesn't mean deployment has failed, just that the Transport service has timed out while waiting for notification of success or failure from the deployer.  The deployment may be succeeding but you'll need to check the deployer logs to know for sure.

You can adjust the length of the polling time for the transport service in cd_transport_conf.xml.  See:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-90CDD51A-766C-4628-B16E-0F3BF7126169
(Login required)