# SDLWeb8.5 : Preparing Deployment Failed due to Polling for notification for destination

Tags: web8, web8.5

We got below error when publish page or component.

> Polling for notification for destination: shcohVft4q4cKPkWh031Sg== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-3675084-66560

[image]

Looking solution and recommendation this issue.

Comment: Look at the Deployer log files. There should be a more thorough stack trace. Edit your question and copy paste that in.

Comment: Similar issue to Tridion 2013. Please see answer here - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8184/2125

Answer (score 1):

> exceeded polling attempts

This tells you that the transport service stopped trying to obtain the status of the deployment, not that there was definitely some error. Check for errors in your deployer logs and also check any timings related to your transaction ID, as it may be the case that your deployment actually succeeded but that it took an unusually long time to do so.

It looks in (what's left of) your screen capture like someone published a component... That could have caused a larger than expected deployment package if the component is used in lots of places. If the package is unusually large then it could definitely take much longer to deploy.

If you'd like to change your transport service polling configuration to increase the number of attempts, the timeout or the polling interval, take a look at the [configuration reference for the polling element](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-90CDD51A-766C-4628-B16E-0F3BF7126169) of cd_transport_conf.xml

Answer (score 0):

When publishing fails in the committing deployment, there are mainly two reasons:

1. Database timeout issue
2. Custom deployer extension related issue.

You will find the details of both of the issues in deployer logs.